# This is will be / This will be

Tags: grammar

I've never seen such a structure like Sentence (1) I think it should be like sentence (2) But I found it everywhere on the internet...
if we have just a future tense why thee is "is" before "will" ???

> 1) This is will be great for me.
>
> 2) This will be great for me.

Which grammar rule can explain such wired structure? (Wired for me of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is not good English grammar. The Internet is filled with poor grammar. People are writing quickly and make mistakes. People who do not know English well may use it on the Internet. And finally people abbreviate on the Internet.

"This is or will be great for me" is perfectly good English. Someone in a hurry may deliberately leave out the "or" in the hope that the reader will supply it. Or someone may just forget to insert the "or."

Comment: The first sentence comes in Inside Out Animation from disney!!!

Comment: @Pixer Do you believe that companies are infallible? Disney caters to the infantile: that is their whole shtick. Disney would be wise to hire a reasonable proportion of employees with a mental age of 2 in order to relate well to its targeted audience. I thought you  were asking what was good English, not what people who think fish talk may imagine to be English.

Comment: Wow... I thought at least their English is better than me. Sorry Bro !!!